# Rich text editor wrap text with contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to design a simple rich text editor using the contenteditable feature and need some help with this function that wraps the selection with tags (eg: `<em>`)

Example:

I start with this

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="editor">123<strong>abc</strong>xyz</div>
```

Selects a some text

```
3<strong>abc</strong>x
```

and then click on the button that executes the tag wrapping function.

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="editor">12<em>3<strong>abc</strong>x</em>yz</div>
```

How can I find the starting and ending of the selection to insert the opening and the closing tags?

I've been stuck for hours, any help would be great.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var italicize = function () {
    document.execCommand('italic');
};​
```

Just call this method whenever you wish to italicize the selected text.

See fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/UdPAC/12/

Comment: is it possible to do this with jquery?

Comment: How do you mean?  It really does not have much to do with jquery.  Can you give me an example/psuedo-code of what you want?